# Why is not the image effected when I use margin-left

Tags: html, css

This question is just to try to understand this example and it works as it should.
I have set this styling  `margin:0 0 0 98px;` on the selector `#sweden dd`
and I want to know the reason why can the image keep it's position when I use the above styling
on `#sweden dd`. I mean when I use margin it used push the surrounding elements away so the specified space in this case 98px could be placed between the description element(`dd`) and the image.

Here is the complete markup and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:small;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            #sweden
            {
                float:left;
                width:300px;
                padding:10px 0;
                border:2px solid #C8CDD2;
            }

            #sweden dl /* block element */
            {
                float:left;
                margin:10px 20px;
                padding:0;
            }

            #sweden dt   /* block element */
            {
                float:right;
                width:162px;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-size:130%;
                letter-spacing:1px;
                color:#627081;
                background:blue;
            }

            #sweden dd
            {
                padding:0;
                margin:0 0 0 98px; /*Keep text lined up in a column */
                font-size:85%;  
                line-height:1.5em;
                color:#666;
                background:red;
            }

            #sweden dl dd.img
            {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            #sweden dd.img img
            {
                float:left;
                margin: 0 8px 0 0;
                padding:4px;
                border:1px solid #D9E0E6;
                border-bottom-color:#C8CDD2;
                border-right-color:#C8CDD2;
                background:#fff;
            }
        </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chapter 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="sweden">
            <dl>
                <dt>Stockholm</dt>
                <dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" 
                   alt="Gamla Stan" /></dd>    
                <dd>This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                    This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                    This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                    This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                    This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan. 
                    This was taken in Gamla Stan. This was taken in Gamla Stan</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/vhLr9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sweden dl dd.img
```

is more specific than

```
#sweden dd
```

so the margin of the first will be applied. Read more about [CSS priority rules](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/) to understand the issue. In this particular case the margin of the first will be applied.

Comment: No you are wrong! look here the margin for selector "#sweden dd" will be applied but for those dd element that has a class with img specified that exist below an dl element will this style be used.

Comment: No I thing you are wrong! look here the margin for selector "#sweden dd" will be applied but for those dd element that has class=img specified that exist below an dl element will this style be used. I home you understand what I mean.

Comment: In both cases dd is a descendant of #sveden. The first applies everywhere because it is more specific than the second. The second's margin will be overwritten by the first's margin in case the dd has the img class. So, we can safely say that in the case the dd has the img class, the margin attribute of the #sweden dd will be overwritten by the margin attribute of the #sweden dl dd.img.

Comment: I mean the first and second selector don't always target the same element. The first doesn't target element dd that doesn't have a class=img. Here is how I understand this. When we have a dd element with class=img the first selector is used and when dd has no img class the second selector is used.

Comment: In fact both of them are used if the img class is present, but if two rules are defining the value of the same attribute, then the value of the rule with higher priority will be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Your margin rule in **#sweden dd** is not getting applied because the margin in **#sweden dl dd.img** is overwriting it and setting it to 0.